# Jenkins Pipeline script. No such property: for class WorkFlowScript

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am getting the above error could you please provide the solution for this, and I had placed peace of code, but entire script is executing successfully but finally its throwing above error and build was failed.

```
pipeline{
     parameters {
        string(name: 'CPU', defaultValue: '40m')
        }
      stage('build') {
        steps{ 
         script{
                  def cpu =  params.CPU
                  bat "mvn -DCPU=${cpu}"
          } } } }
```

Exception Error:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property:  for class: WorkFlowScript

Comment: Your error is not generated from the shared code. The above looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Some value of a variable is missing.
Add a println line befor
`bat "mvn -DCPU=${cpu}"`
and check if the value of "cpu" get printed.
If it gets printed then some other variable value is mising.